"smart" tags being not helpful as they are now
Preparing to ask a question about smartmontools, I tired to filter existing questions using the correct tag(s).
However searching for tags matching "smart" I realized that none of the tags displayed has any description (bad per se), and even more:
I wonder whether separate tags smart (S.M.A.R.T.?), smartctl and smartmontools are all needed.
AFAIK, there is no "tag hierarchy", but if there existed such, I'd suggest:

smart

smartmontools

smartctl





Clarification
So what I propose (besides that I think hierarchical tags would be nice to have) is:

The person that created those tags (that would be the best one to know the intentions) should add at least a short summary what thae tag should be used for
Adding a longer description would be nice also
After having a description of those tags, another person could decide whether all of those are really needed (make sense), and maybe suggest to obsolete some tags.
Once some tags are obsoleted, associated questions could/should be re-tagged to use only the recommended tags (IMHO obsolete tags will still be re-used (as long as it's possible) when existing questions still use such tags, because when looking for a related problem, one might find questions using such tags obsoleted by then).

Hopefully it's clearer now.
English is not my native language.

Since, as you say, there isn't a hierarchy (which would be great but quite complicated network wide), can you please clarify what you are proposing here? Are you saying some of these tags should be removed?
